# Word Field CardText limit

Tags: ms-word

I like the idea of Word spelling out a number for me in certain scenarios as follows:

```
{ REF BookmarkName \* CardText }
```

However, when I try to spell out the total price of a quotation it fails to do so if the value is too high. Does anyone know where the limit is? Is there any way to overcome it?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tour, where it says, for example "Don't ask about...Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Answer (score 0):

This feature dates back to around 1990, when the amounts people worked with were much more modest than now. There is, indeed, a built-in limitation of six digits before the decimal point: 999'999 is the largest integer the field switch `\* cardtext` supports.

It is possible to have higher numbers, but it requires combining field codes to work around the limitation. Many, many years ago, a group of us in the Word forum on Compuserve figured out a way to do this and I posted it on my website (http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/NbrFAQ.htm#Millions). I copy it verbatim, below:

> There are special formatting switches that allow you to display a
>   number as text, either with or without "dollars". (For more
>   information on the number formatting switches, look under Switches;
>   field switches; number formats in Word's Help Index.) But the program
>   is limited to displaying the information for numbers less than one
>   million. In order to display amounts in the millions as text, you need
>   to use a combination of nested fields.  Example:

```
{ QUOTE { = SET n 1999999 }
   { IF n < 1000000 "{ = n \*cardtext }" "{ = int(n/1000000) \* cardtext } million 
     { SET r { = MOD(n, 1000000) } }
     { IF r = 0 "" "{ = r \* cardtext }" }" 
   } \* caps \* CharFormat 
}
```

> Displays one million nine hundred ninety-nine thousand nine hundred
>   ninety-nine.
>
> The `QUOTE` field keeps everything together. The number you
>   want to work with is bookmarked in the `SET` field. Then you test
>   whether the number is greater than one million. If it is, divide it by
>   one million, then get the integer of this result for the words in
>   millions. Next, determine the remainder and get the text for it.

*Note: The line breaks in the code section are for readability purposes, only! The entire field code should be created with NO line breaks.*

For those not familiar with working with field codes in Word:

- Insert the field brackets using { } using Ctrl+F9; you may *not* type them in any other way!
- Observe the single spaces around operators such as =, >, <
- Use Alt+F9 to toggle between field codes and field result
- Click in the field (set) and press F9 to force the field result to update